# Can't stop my timeout when i clear the div

Tags: javascript

Hey I have a `setTimeOut();`

Which calls itself over and over.

The problem is i want to clear it when the user closes the given div, however i don't know how to abort it with `clearTimeout()` by using the id of the timeout that was running.

Heres an example of my function:

```
upgrade(end , new Date().getTime() / 1000 ,text,false);
//happens when you clicks on something

function upgrade(end, start, text, timerId){        

    var per = ( (new Date().getTime() / 1000) - start ) / ( end - start ) * 100;

    if(per>100)per=100;
    if(per<0)per = 0;
    text.innerHTML = Math.round(per)+'%';
timerId = setTimeout(function() { upgrade_bar(end, start, text, timerId) } , 17);
}
```

Now lets say the user wants to close this timer. How can i do `clearTimeout(timerId)` when the id's scope is limited to the function?

I have for example this:

```
document.getElementById("sbmt").addEventListener("click", remove_div, false);
//this happens during windows.onload
```

Somehow my function `remove_div` has to clear it. But the time out's id won't have the scope.

What are my options here to allow me to clear time out's ?

Comment: Could you show us how exactly the upgrade function is called when something is clicked? And are you trying to cancel all timeOuts, or just specific ones ?

Comment: when the object is clicked it calls up a function... inside that function it calls my `upgrade()` function as shown in the question (first line of my example code is how i begin the time out)

Comment: But what object, how is it relevant to `sbmt`, and how to know what timeout to cancel, or should all timeouts be canceled ?

Comment: Also, `timerId` is global, so that's accessible anywhere ?

Comment: no timerId is only found in that function i had forgot to put `var` but does it not just keep creating a new idea every time, which is a problem

Comment: I still don't get it, when clicking sbmt what div should be removed, is the upgrade function called on multiple elements, and how do you distinguish those elements.

Comment: The simple solution is to just return the timeout -> http://jsfiddle.net/bzPub/ , another solution would be to attach the timer to the element -> http://jsfiddle.net/bzPub/1/, but it's hard to know how to do this without more context ?

Comment: @adeneo http://jsfiddle.net/LFBh4/ this should explain best the issue :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LFBh4/1/

Comment: @adeneo i tried to scale it  to multiple progress bars to test it : http://jsfiddle.net/LFBh4/4/ seems to not work once i do that

Comment: Of course not, you only have one update function, ID's must be unique etc. If you'd like to instantiate the function multiple times you should prototype it and call it with the `new` keyword on elements with unique ID's

Comment: Or you could do this -> http://jsfiddle.net/LFBh4/7/

Comment: @adeneo could you make that an answer i believe it will help most people due to its scalability.

Comment: post it yourself, and accept it. As you see in the fiddle the timers are stored on an element level as you can attach any property to an element, like `bar._timer` in this case, which can then be canceled with `clearTimeout(document.getElementById('bar')._timer)` as the timer is now a property of the element itself and is accessible anywhere.

Comment: Will it also clear if i remove the div ? such as change it's parent's innerHTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this.

First off, you could return the `timerId` from `upgrade`. You'd store that value in a variable which could be accessed by your other function.

Alternatively, you can create a variable inside the parent object (in your case, it looks like that'd be `window`) which stores the id.

For example:

```
function upgrade(end, start, text, timerId) {
    // do stuff
    return setTimeout(/*params*/);
}
var timerId = upgrade(/*params*/);

function remove_div(event) {
    // do stuff
    clearTimeout(this.timerId);
}

document.getElementById("sbmt").addEventListener("click", remove_div.bind({'timerId': timerId, 'element': document.getElementById("sbmt")}, false);
```

Or:

```
var timerId;
function upgrade(end, start, text) {
    // do stuff
    timerId = setTimeout(/*params*/);
}

function remove_div(event) { 
    // do stuff
    clearTimeout(timerId);
}

document.getElementById("sbmt").addEventListener("click", remove_div, false);
```

Comment: Your first example seems best if i wanted to create multiple timers but, if i return the setTimeout, does it keep running the function? As you can see in mine the Timeout calls the same function it is in, thus acting like a setInterval in some respects.

Comment: Returning the `setTimeout` doesn't return the function. Rather, it returns what `setTimeout` returns (which is, I believe, the id).

Answer (score 1):

You need access to the id returned by setTimeout, as you point out it's not accessible the way you have it written, but it's a simple matter to move it out.

For example:

```
var timeout;
function start() {
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
        start();
    }, 200);
}

function stop() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

Comment: Rather than using a global variable, I think it's better to store this as a property of one function or the other (e.g., `start.timeout = window.setTimeout(...)` and `window.clearTimeout(start.timeout)`). This still prevents re-entrancy, but at least it won't pollute the global namespace . . .

Comment: @ruakh I don't disagree, polluting global is a bad idea, typically if I have something like this I would encapsulate it in a single function with properties for start stop so that scope is restricted to that function, but I thought this was a more straight forward answer to the posed question.

Answer (score 0):

you can hook the timeout id to the window scope like so.

```
 window['timerId'] = setTimeout(function() { upgrade_bar(end, start, text, timerId) } , 17);
```

replace `timerId` with `window['timerId']` or `window.timerId` so you can explicitly hook it to the global scope.

and clear it like so

```
 clearTimeout(window['timerId']);
```

or

```
 window.clearTimeout(window.timerId);
```

btw `timerId` is not a local variable. this `var timerId` would have made it local.

Comment: I think this works, but is there a reason for the inconsistency in the way you refer to window.timerId? Why refer to it as an array in the first 2 lines and then as an attribute in the 3rd?

Comment: How would this work if you made multiple timeouts assigned to window would it not overwrite `timerId`

Comment: just syntax variation i guess, you'll have more freedom with the array variation i.e. spaces in the name thus making it possible to have a more unique name. their both the same though.

Comment: @Dave when you call the function clearTimeout you are essentially overwriting the variable that holds the setTimeout function anyways. so no.

Comment: Hmm not very scalable then @jayharris :(

Comment: @Dave i dropped the assignment on the clearTimeout function so it won't 'overwrite' the timerId, but i still don't understand how this isn't a solution or scalable